# subsetting dynamically -- subsetting by a variable that is defined in a function

Tags: r, char

```
v1 = c(1,2,3)
v2 = c("a","b",NA)
X = data.frame(v1,v2)

f = function(X,d){
    subset(X,is.na(d)==0)
    }
f(X,"v2")
```

How can I get the subset of X for which any given column (inputted into the argument of a function) isn't missing?

Answer (score 5):

Note: The function `subset` should not be used in functions but interactively only (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863081/1627235)).

```
f <- function(X, d) {
  X[!is.na(X[d]), ]
}

> f(X,"v2")
  v1 v2
1  1  a
2  2  b
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use complete.cases you can input a vector of column names.

```
f <- function(X,d) {
     X[complete.cases(X[,d]),]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function. Just do:

```
X[!is.na(X$v2),]
```

Comment: True,  but my interpretation of the OP's question was how to write this sort of function in the general case, where rewriting the arguments to the `[` operator might not be so simple.

Comment: Yes, after I posted I wondered if the question was about genuinely needing a function or just not knowing how to subset without `subset`. Others have since provided answers to the former, however.